# How to wrap a group of div inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html code:

```
<div id="elem">
    <div data-foo="aaa">a</div>
    <div data-foo="aaa">a</div>
    <div data-foo="aaa">a</div>
    <div data-foo="bbb">b</div>
    <div data-foo="bbb">b</div>
    <div data-foo="ccc">c</div>
    <div data-foo="ccc">c</div>
    <div data-foo="ccc">c</div>
    <div data-foo="ccc">c</div>
    <div data-foo="ccc">c</div>
</div>
```

I need to group all those different `div[data-foo]` inside a div like this:

```
    <div id="elem">
        <div class="wrap">
            <div data-foo="aaa">a</div>
            <div data-foo="aaa">a</div>
            <div data-foo="aaa">a</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div data-foo="bbb">b</div>
            <div data-foo="bbb">b</div>
        </div>
        <div class="wrap">
            <div data-foo="ccc">c</div>
            <div data-foo="ccc">c</div>
            <div data-foo="ccc">c</div>
            <div data-foo="ccc">c</div>
            <div data-foo="ccc">c</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Those `div[data-foo]` contents are dynamically generated. I cant figure out how to solve this problem. Could someone help me please?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the possible values, you may do this :

```
$('#elem [data-foo]').each(function(){
  var $this = $(this),
      $w = $(this).parent().find('.wrap:has([data-foo="'+$this.data('foo')+'"])');
  if (!$w.length) $w = $('<div>').addClass('wrap').appendTo($this.parent());
  $w.append(this);
});
```

Answer (score 2):

try this...

```
PrevAttr= '';
        $('div#elem div').each(function(){

            attr = $(this).attr('data-foo');

            if(attr != PrevAttr)
            { PrevAttr = attr;
              $('div#elem div[data-foo='+attr+']').wrapAll('<div class="wrap"></div>')
            }
        })
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var array = [];
    // get all unique data-foo
    $('#elem div').each(function(){
      var fooData = $(this).data('foo');
      if($.inArray(fooData, array) ==-1)
         array.push(fooData); 
    });

    // wrap all unique data-foo divs in wrap div
    for(var i=0;i<array.length;i++)
    {
        $('[data-foo="'+array[i]+'"]').wrapAll("<div class='wrap'></div>");
    }
});
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GajcZ/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.wrapAll()` for that:

```
$('[data-foo="ccc"]').wrapAll("<div class='wrap'></div>");
$('[data-foo="bbb"]').wrapAll("<div class='wrap'></div>");
$('[data-foo="aaa"]').wrapAll("<div class='wrap'></div>");
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/3qtrP/)**

Comment: I cant use this way. The data-foo is always changing, like this `div[data-foo='jfn338']` or this `div[data-foo='i438fu']`

Comment: Well, why don't you fetch all the `data-foo` values and then any time they change (they must change based on something - events, time) recalculate the selector and call `wrapAll` on them?

Comment: @RamonVasconcelos: you did not mentioned that earlier :\ . dystroy and other people had provided good answer. see them.